# How is CTRL-R (reverse-i-search) is implemented in bash terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

Example of the reverse search:

```
(reverse-i-search)`grep': git log | grep master
```

What is the algorithm used to find a suggestion? 
Where does its search space come from ?

A pointer to its source code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure on the code, but taking a stab in the dark, it may be a search upon your ~/.bash_history file

Comment: @JNevill It's always the in-memory history, which may have been initialized from a history file when the shell instance started.

Comment: About the ~/bash_history: If I update the ~/.bash_history with some new commands, an existing terminal's reverse search does not suggest those newly inserted commands: @JNevill

Comment: @chepner. Reverse search can suggest from the most recent commands executed in the same terminal. It **may** be initialized with the ~/.bash_history at the start of the terminal, but it also takes into account the commands executed in the terminal since start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reverse-i-search is part of [GNU Readline Library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). The Readline Library facilitates reading line along with editing facilities. The entire source code can be found [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline).

#### Source of search space

Following code snippet from the source shows how the source file for history is determined :

```
/* Return the string that should be used in the place of this
   filename.  This only matters when you dont specify the
   filename to read_history (), or write_history (). */
static char *
history_filename (filename)
     const char *filename;
{
  char *return_val;
  const char *home;
  int home_len;

  return_val = filename ? savestring (filename) : (char *)NULL;

  if (return_val)
    return (return_val);

  home = sh_get_env_value ("HOME");
#if defined (_WIN32)
  if (home == 0)
    home = sh_get_env_value ("APPDATA");
#endif

  if (home == 0)
    return (NULL);
  else
    home_len = strlen (home);

  return_val = (char *)xmalloc (2 + home_len + 8); /* strlen(".history") == 8 */
  strcpy (return_val, home);
  return_val[home_len] = '/';
#if defined (__MSDOS__)
  strcpy (return_val + home_len + 1, "_history");
#else
  strcpy (return_val + home_len + 1, ".history");
#endif

  return (return_val);
}
```

- `savestring()` is defined in [savestring.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/savestring.c) which simply copies the string  `filename` if it is defined.
- `sh_get_env_value()` function is implemented using `getenv()` function ( provided by `<stdlib.h>` ) used to get an environment value ( Refer [man page getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) ).
- As shown, `.bash_history` or `.history` ( this is the file that is used in case the function returns `NULL` ) will be used as source for implementing the search on a Linux system.

*Source* : [histfile.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/histfile.c)

#### How history is stored

- The searchable history is stored in a [`HIST_ENTRY`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/history.h)( history list ) array. The data from `.bash_history` is added to this array. *Source* : [history.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/history.c)
- The record of the commands entered in current session are saved in [`_rl_saved_line_for_history`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/misc.c).
- These two are combined into a [`_rl_search_cxt`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/rlprivate.h) instance member array ( `cxt->lines[]` ) using which the search is performed.

#### Algorithm

The actual search is performed using [`_rl_isearch_dispatch()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/isearch.c) and [`_rl_search_getchar()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/isearch.c) function.

*Short Summary* :
The algorithm reads character by character the input deciding what it should do. In case of no interrupts, it adds the character to the search string searching for it in the array. If the string is not found, it moves to next element skipping over same string found again and strings shorter in length than current length of search string. ( Read `default :` in `switch` for exact details in `_rl_isearch_dispatch()` )

In case the string is not found, the bell is dinged. Else, it displays the string but doesn't actually moves there in history list till user accepts the location.

Comment: If one wants a better indexed and searchable source, it can also be found at [Github: JuliaLang/readline](https://github.com/JuliaLang/readline/tree/9e182c9a057c8f3eea14bf5dc13f047fbb260abd)

Comment: How frequently is the `${HOME}/.history` file is read? Because sometimes i see that the `${HOME}/.history` file contains a command, but the CTRL-R search cannot recommend it. That command is written by another terminal, but the current terminal that executes CTRL-R does not recommend that. Is there a way to force-load the most recent `${HOME}/.history` file again ?

Comment: @HakanBaba You can force-load the most recent `.bash_history` file using `history -r`. However if the other terminal window is still open, the command won't show up in the file until you close the terminal. To add the command to the history file without closing the terminal, use `history -a` to add the terminal's current command history to the history file. And then reload the history using `history -r`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I execute `history -a` with every command in every terminal using the PROMPT_COMMAND env var already. My problem is with `history -r`.  With running `history -r`, not only the search space of CTRL-R expands. But the list of previous commands also change (What I see with UpArrow). I do not want to re-order the list of previously executed commands in the current terminal. I only want to expand the suggestion meta-set for CTRL-R.